# SSRS 2008 R2 Report Builder 3.0: Offset Date Default Start Time

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-2008-r2

I allow the user to enter in what start date and end date they need.I set my start and end date parameters to @Start and @End. They have no values stored in them, rather in my code I have 
    ....Between @Start and @End. 
The dates entered by the user gets passed into my program instead of me specifying what the user is allowed to enter  in the parameter properties.
My problem is I want the default start of each date picked to be 5:00 AM Instead of 0:00 AM. This way when the user picks for example: 2/20 and 2/21, they can retrieve date from 5:00 AM- 5:00 AM. This enables my program to show data past midnight, which is necessary because my data stops at 3:00 AM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `DateAdd` function to add 5 hours to get 2/20/2013 5:00 AM

Look at this:

```
=DateAdd("h",5,Parameters!StartDate.Value)
```

**Edit**

you can add this line of code in one of the following:

**Dataset's parameters section**

- Right click on your dataset
- click on parameters section
- Click on the `FX` button, and put there the line of code

Use this when you use parameters to filter your SQL query

**Report's field (i.e textbox, table cell etc..)**

- Right click on the field
- Click on the field expression option, and put there the line of code

The result looks like that:
[image]

Comment: That worked exactly how I wanted it to. I have found that solution before but I was always putting it in the wrong location. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I glad it worked, please consider mark the answer as the right one so others will find it useful also. You can do it by clicking on the V sign.